# F# command-line compiler: setting the CPU architecture

Tags: .net, f#, x86, x86-64

Is it possible to compile an F# program from the command line for a specific architecture, *without a project file or using MSBUILD*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--platform:[x86|Itanium|x64|anycpu]`

For example: `fsc --platform:x86 ...`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) for the full set of options.